# Create video with effects from image

Tags: python, opencv, image-processing

I am currently working on [a project](http://jlengrand.github.com/FaceMovie/) where I generate several images and then transform them into a video. 
I am using OpenCV for the whole image processing thing, and especially [cv.WriteFrame](http://opencv.willowgarage.com/documentation/reading_and_writing_images_and_video.html).

Even though it is working quite well, I would like to add some effects for image transition.
Simple things in fact, I would like the images to blend into each other to avoid the "violent" way it is currently done.

I also have problems with the fps in cv.WriteFrames (which is not accurate).

I searched on the internet without finding any library/utility to do that, so I started thinking about implementing it by myself. It would be quite a hassle though.

Would you know about an option to do such a thing?
I am open to any solution !

Thanks

Comment: Nice image alignment (and also nice idea for an app, if it doesn't exist), did you need to use face recognition or just somehow aligned the eyes?

Comment: Thx, glad you like it. It still in early age of development, but the Windowd version is quite stable. I used face recognition, and plan to go for eyes in order to add rotation capabilities

Comment: Not sure if this suggestion works but maybe by using feature matching inside the faces' rectangles, and applying homography transformations, you could align rotated faces. (This is what i mean: http://docs.opencv.org/doc/tutorials/features2d/feature_homography/feature_homography.html#feature-homography )

Comment: Hum, not dumb; I'll keep it in mind !

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To have a smooth transition you most likely have to put some extra frames between the 2 images. Those extra frames could be the 2 images progressively adding each other.
Usually opencv addWeighted is used to blend 2 images, it has parameters to set the weights.

addWeighted docs:

http://docs.opencv.org/modules/core/doc/operations_on_arrays.html#addweighted

Comment: Hey, Thanks for the idea. That was basically exactly what I was planning to implement by hand :)

Comment: Tried it, it works like a charm. Thanks for the idea, it avoids to include a new library in the project

Answer (score 1):

Well, I've never worked with OpenCV, but if you want to do a fade in or fade out I could envision doing something like creating frames that have progressively more alpha transparency and adding them into the stack thats being written to the video file. Something like that could be done in just a few lines of code with PIL.